# Getting error while invoke chaincode as "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 6"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to invoke the chaincode function however getting error "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 6".

I have check my chainocode as its fine and running good. I could not understand why its give error. as there is correct number of argument in function.

Chaincode function

```
func (s *SmartContract) recordProduce(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {

    if len(args) != 5 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 5")
    }

    var Produce = Produce{ProduceName: args[1], Health: args[2], Owner : arg[3], FarmID: args[4]}

    ProduceAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(Produce)
    APIstub.PutState(args[0], ProduceAsBytes)

    return shim.Success(nil)
}
```

Invoke.js

```
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath =  path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'basic-network', 'connection.json');

async function main() {
    try {

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

        // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
        const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
        if (!userExists) {
            console.log('An identity for the user "user1" does not exist in the wallet');
            console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
            return;
        }

        // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
        const gateway = new Gateway();
        await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'user1', discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true } , eventHandlerOptions: {
            strategy: null
        } 
    });

        // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('dfarmchannel');

        // Get the contract from the network.
        const contract = network.getContract('produce-app');


        await contract.submitTransaction('recordProduce', 'PR12', 'Banana', 'Good', 'Abhi', 'FARM111');
        console.log('Transaction has been submitted');

        // Disconnect from the gateway.
        await gateway.disconnect();

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to submit transaction: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

main();
```

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your source code has the error message "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 5", but you have got "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 6". 
Could you be sure that you are working with the correct version of the chaincode?

In case you've updated the chaincode, check that you've run `peer chaincode install` and `peer chaincode upgrade` with the correct source code and the version number.